# How to handle a voice call using WebRTC in background in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-background-mode, webrtc-ios

I'm working on an iOS Swift project in which I need to implement a video call using WebRTC. I implemented and is working on the foreground mode. But when I close the app, the call gets disconnected. How to handle the voice call in background mode also. Please help me. I didn't work on the background mode.